# Formula bar view changes when document is saved and reopened

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2007

I have an Excel 2007 document with a lot of formulas of the format:

`SUMIFS(view1[COLUMN1],view1[COLUMN2],$C13,view1[COLUMN3],I$10)`

but when I save the sheet and reopen it each formula is changed to the much less readable (but still accurate) format:

`SUMIFS(data!$F$2:$F$65536,data!$B$2:$B$65536,$C13,data!$K$2:$K$65536,I$10)`

The formulas all still work, I just want to keep the view as `view1[COLUMN1]` to make it more readable and to make edits easier.

How do I stop Excel from automatically changing how this shows up in the formula bar?

Answer (score 0):

Suggestion might help on your situation.
Add a column header to your data and convert your data set to a table.

The benefit of using table is your formula will shows the column name instead of cell reference.

It should able to fix your problem.

You can check the below url for more details about Excel Table.

http://www.jkp-ads.com/Articles/Excel2007Tables.asp